# Combining together 7 correlated normalized scores into one final score

Tags: correlation, model

I am currently analyzing drivers behaviour. To this, for each driver ID, I calculated some scores, as you can see in the correlation matrix below: [image]

All the scores are normalized, with 0 -> very good, 1 -> very bad. I want to assign to each driver some sort of number saying if he's a bad driver or a good driver.

At first, I tried clustering based on the scores, but the result has been lackluster. 
(Also using PCA beforehand)

Then, I want to define a function: $$ f : Scores -> Score_{final} $$
At first, I thought the final score could be the sum of each score. 
However, this would be equivalent to doing a linear combination with all scores weighting the same, moreover I am not taking into account the correlation between scores, thus leading to poor results.

Does someone have any idea on how I could handle this?

EDIT: Adding data as requested:

Here I have a plot of the distribution of the scores:
[image]

While here I have the cumulative distribution of variance explained by PCA, which leads me to believe that it is not useful: 
[image]

By the way, I have tried many different clustering techniques: KNN, DBSCAN and affinity propagation, all leading to a silhouette score of about 0.28

Comment: You mentioned PCA.  What didn't work?  Can you show a biplot.  Are all your scores non-negative? Is it possible for you to post/link to data?

Comment: @GeorgM.Goerg I am glad you asked, I added some more reasoning.

Comment: I understand that your scores are already normalized; I suggest to a) use raw scores and b) log-transform (or log(1 + x) if some are == 0) scores that are heavily right skewed ("SpeedScore" + the last 3). The reason being that PCA operates on the covariance matrix and your scores are clearly non-normal (not even marginally) -- so as a first step I d try to get them as normal as possible w/o estimating any parameters and then see if you can extract scores from raw data. Then plot a correlation matrix and do the PCA exercise again to see if you get better results.  any chance to post raw data?

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately I cannot share the data.

Comment: No problem.  Did the log suggestion work out?  As another alternative you can try NMF algorithms.